# How to reset array of object duplicate value set empty value

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, typescript-typings

How to set the duplicate value is an array object to empty string.

```
 const arr = [
  { type: 'F', name: "Fun Box", age: 12 },
  { type: 'X', name: "X Box", age: 13 },
  { type: 'X', name: "X Box", age: 14 },
  { type: 'X', name: "X Box Test", age: 15 },
  { type: 'B', name: "Best Box", age: 16 },
  { type: 'B', name: "Best Box Test", age: 15 },
  { type: 'B', name: "Best Box", age: 17 },
  { type: null, name: "Box One", age: 18 },
];
```

expected result like below:

```
    const resultArr = [
  { type: 'F', name: 'Fun Box', age: 12 },
  { type: 'X', name: 'X Box', age: 13 },
  { type: 'X', name: '', age: 14 },
  { type: 'X', name: 'X Box Test', age: 15 },
  { type: 'B', name: 'Best Box', age: 16 },
  { type: 'B', name: 'Best Box Test', age: 15 },
  { type: 'B', name: '', age: 17 },
  { type: null, name: 'Box One', age: 18 }
]
```

I have tried but not getting exact result,

```
arr.map((res, i=index) => {
      const getNum = i === 0 ? i : i - 1;
      const prev = arr[getNum].name;

      if (res.name === prev) {
          res.name = '';
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can keep track of the names you've seen with a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) while you're [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)ping over the data to create the new data.

```js
const arr = [
  { type: "F", name: "Fun Box", age: 12 },
  { type: "X", name: "X Box", age: 13 },
  { type: "X", name: "X Box", age: 14 },
  { type: "X", name: "X Box Test", age: 15 },
  { type: "B", name: "Best Box", age: 16 },
  { type: "B", name: "Best Box Test", age: 15 },
  { type: "B", name: "Best Box", age: 17 },
  { type: null, name: "Box One", age: 18 },
];

const seenNames = new Set();

const newArr = arr.map((el) => {
  if(seenNames.has(el.name)) {
    // If we've seen the name already, replace it with an empty string.
    return {...el, name: ''};
  }
  // Record the name, and return the element as-is.
  seenNames.add(el.name);
  return el;
});

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) in a closure for seen names and map either the object or take a new object with empty `name` property.

```js
const 
    data = [{ type: 'F', name: "Fun Box", age: 12 }, { type: 'X', name: "X Box", age: 13 }, { type: 'X', name: "X Box", age: 14 }, { type: 'X', name: "X Box Test", age: 15 }, { type: 'B', name: "Best Box", age: 16 }, { type: 'B', name: "Best Box Test", age: 15 }, { type: 'B', name: "Best Box", age: 17 }, { type: null, name: "Box One", age: 18 }],
    result = data.map((seen => o => seen.has(o.name) || !seen.add(o.name)
        ? { ...o, name: '' }
        : o
    )(new Set));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: If you saw this code in a code review situation, could you understand what it's doing right away?

Comment: @AKX, it depends on the background. and yes, i could read it.

Comment: Though you might be able to read it. The intent of an answer is to be understandable for OP. Given the information shown in the question I think this causes more questions than it answers.

Comment: updated exact data. Hope now you can understand why I raised the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Your function is incorrect. It only compares the current value with the previous one, and always clears the name at index 0.

A more effective approach would be to initialize an array of strings before the map function, and update this array whenever a new name is encountered. Then, simply check if the current name already exists in the array.

```
const existingNames = [];
arr.map((res) => {
  if(existingNames.includes(res.name)) {
    res.name = '';
  } else {
    existingNames.push(res.name)
  }
  return res;
});
```

Comment: This modifies the original `arr` in-place, which is generally not a good thing.